# Ошибка в программе Python

Tags: python

Нашёл программу, с условием " Ввести натуральное число и определить, верно ли, что в его записи есть
две одинаковые цифры (не обязательно стоящие рядом)".
Пример:

> Введите натуральное число:
>   12342
>   Да.

Пример:

> Введите натуральное число:
>   12345
>   Нет.

Но выдаётся ошибка, помогите исправить, пожалуйста!

```py
from __future__ import print_function
A = int(input("a = "))
a1 = a % 10
a = a // 10
k = 0
while a>0:
  a2 = a % 10
  if a1==a2: k+=1;
  a = a // 10
  a1 = a2
if k>0: print("Да")
else: print("Нет")
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (mest recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Win10Pro/Desktop/ПР 45.py", line 3, in <module>
    a1 = a % 10
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: Как вы думаете, для чего выдаётся ошибка? Читайте и исправляйте.

Comment: вы записываете input в переменную A

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка `править` под вопросом)

Answer (score 1):

строчки 3 и 4. Нужно вычислять от A.

```
a1 = A % 10
a = A // 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Для питона переменные `A` и `a` совсем разные, то есть питон чувствителен к регистру. Просто напишите вместо `A = int(...` - `a = int(...`

Answer (score 1):

Вашу задачу можно решить проще:

```py
>>> def has_doubbles(n: int) -> bool:
...   return len(set(str(n))) != len(str(n))
...
>>> has_doubbles(123456)
False
>>> has_doubbles(123454)
True
```

Если в числе есть повторения, то множество цифр этой строки будет иметь меньшую размерность, чем длина строкового представления этого числа

Answer (score -1):

поставь `a = a //  10` выше `a1 = a % 10`

Comment: ``a`` точно так же останется не определена.